# $F$ is Lipschitzian if for every $f$ AC，$F◦f$ is AC

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let a function $F$ on [a, b] be such that the
composition $F◦f$ is absolutely continuous for every absolutely continuous function
$f$ with values in [a, b]. Prove that $F$ is Lipschitzian.

I found it proved by Fichtenholz, but unfortunately it's written in Russian. Could anyone show the main idea of the proof? 3x

Maybe one can follow this:http://www.mathnet.ru/links/fcd916a74bbfdb3911ca6b52105af230/sm6853.pdf